# Xcode4.4 unittest did not finish

Tags: unit-testing, warnings, xcode4.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some of my unit tests tests are not finishing in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308297/some-of-my-unit-tests-tests-are-not-finishing-in-xcode-4-4)

I've just upgraded to XCode 4.4. I've created a new project and included unittesting. When running the tests I get a warning "All tests did not finish".

Colleagues with clean installs of xcode 4.4 have exactly the same problem. They did not type a single letter of code and only created a new project that included unittests.

What did we do wrong and how can we solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this.  It was caused by a bug in the code ("unrecognized selector sent to instance"), which caused the tests to hang.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I noticed that my original test class (MyAppTests), inserted by Xcode, had no tests.  So in the test output I had

```
Test Suite 'MyAppTests' started at 2012-08-18 14:30:27 +0000
Test Suite 'MyAppTests' finished at 2012-08-18 14:30:27 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
```

I then inserted

```
- (void)testNothing {
}
```

into MyAppTests.m and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar issue.

Scenario: Create a new iOS single-view app with unit tests. Xcode generates an Tests class with a testExample method. testExample has an unconditional STFail(), so the tests should always fail. Running the tests via Command+U, 9 times out of 10 Xcode says "Test Succeeded". About 50% of the times 10 the toolbar also says "No Issues", the other 50% it displays an error while still saying "Test Succeeded".

Looking at the log, there is always a "All tests did not finish" warning.

This looks like a timing issue: If I add an [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3] in testExample, the test target consistently fails, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this (duplicate) question for a possible workaround: [Some of my unit tests tests are not finishing in XCode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308297/some-of-my-unit-tests-tests-are-not-finishing-in-xcode-4-4/12386018#12386018)